# Should I include whole bower_components and node_modules folder in my web project?

Tags: npm, bower, web-deployment, webdeploy

When I download a package in bower or npm, many irrelevant/not-useful files also 
get included especially in npm packages. I generally only include .css or .js files of that package for e.g. in bootstrap e.t.c. But for package like polymer or Anjular.js or Electron we need multiple other file too. So when I deploy my project should I include the complete folder or just copy the required files separately or is there any other approach ?

Comment: yes good thing is to include them because you are installing some plugins which are developed by some other folks.so the dependencies may effect and run in to issues if you filter it as you like . Let the default folders structure stay .. some times there would be a bunch of scrapy files in plugin but they have their cause while developed ..

Comment: but then the over all size of project will be too large.

Comment: I would like to know How are you deploying . If you want to deploy including dependencies the way you are thinking is fine . My suggestion is  try  with heroku  it is free and a good one to deploy angular apps . we use it and no space problems with load of plugins

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to your production server, a good approach would be to only include the files you are actually using. You should also create an optimized file to serve to the client.
To achieve that, you normally have a deploy script that generates one or more minified .css or .js files (for example, vendor.js for libraries and bundle.js for your code).

This script can be build with tools like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or you can use a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [Jspm](http://jspm.io/).

You can create your own Grunt or Gulp script like the ones in [this website](http://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/).

When using a module bundler and modern javascript to organize your code, you'll build, for example, an entry javascript file (bundle.js) that will look like

```
import {MyLibrary} from 'my-library';
import {AnOtherLibrary} from 'an-other-library';

console.log(MyLibrary.saySomething());
```

In this case, Webpack handles the node_modules imports and the creation / minification / concatenation of the production version of .js files.

As you said, there are multiple files to be included (js, css or even fonts) so configuring your scripts may take some time. Try finding a [Yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/) that uses your frameworks, and use the deploy scripts others already created for this purpose. [This one](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) uses AngularJS, Bower and Grunt. [This one](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) uses Webpack and ReactJS.